# Is it possible to retrieve an item randomly and modify it with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking to retrieve an item randomly from my collection and modify it with a fixed value, unfortunately I can't find anything to do this in a single query. I have looked at the pipelines that aggregate () offers but none of them allow me to modify my database.

Comment: it is not possible with single query. do two steps first find and second update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to play with `$sample` and `$merge` aggregation stages:

```
db.test.aggregate(
[{
    $sample: {
        size: 1
    }
}, 
{
    $addFields: {  // you may also look at $project
        test: 1
    }
}, 
{
    $merge: {
        into: "test",
        on: "_id"
    }
}
])
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your query works, if for example I want to modify in my DB the field "isAvailable" in order to pass it to false automatically, I must modify your "test" by "isAvailable" and "_id" by false? 
Anyway, thanks for your answer, I'll keep looking!

Comment: not sure about boolean value, but the idea is like: `{ $project : { isAvailable: "false"} }`, in this case `isAvailable` will be string, how to work with bool itself should be additionally investigated

Comment: Even if it's in a thong it's not a big deal, I could fix it later, so it would look like this in your opinion? Because it doesn't return anything unfortunately
`const search = [
    { $project: { isAvailable: "false"} }, 
    { $addFields: { isAvailable: 1 } },
    { $sample: { size: 1 } },
    { $merge: {into: "isAvailable:", on: "false" } }
]`

Comment: no, 1. $addFields was just example how you can change the result, in your case you need to use $project. 2. `into`: should contain a collection name. 3. `on` should contain "_id". 4. The query itself should not return anything because of `$merge` stage, so the whole query results has been merged into the provided collection. To see result, you need to query the collection again with just $match

Comment: Ok great I just succeeded to modify in my DB, but if there are several lines that have false I could not recover with $match easily? Is it possible to recover reliably the line that has been modified before? Thank you very much, it's been several days that I was blocked and you have just made me advance a big step!

Comment: `Is it possible to recover reliably the line that has been modified before` - I think it's up to your $match query whether you can add this or no.

Comment: Okok well I'll look at it all, I thank you very much for your help, you just saved me ^^